# Unable to launch iOS app written in Swift on device due to lower version error

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-catalina

I created a new iOS app project in Swift language, using Xcode 11.6 running on macOS 10.15 Catalina.

But when I try to run the app on a connected device, I get the following error:

[image]

How I can lower the app's deployment target version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means You current app deployment version is higher than the current using device. Choose the device iOS version greater than equal to iOS 13.6.
Even you can change the Deployment target as per your device but you should care full.

eg. Lets say an app has been done with deployment target as iOS 10 and using many api (may be) has been deprecated or not there in iOS 9. So if you run the app on iOS 9 device version it will not run (will give same error as in question) though you can change the deployment target to iOS 9 to run on device. But it could be harmful. Your app might crash. So better use device higher version than deployment target.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the project file in the project navigator, select the correct target in the outline view and set the value for **Target** under **Deployment Info** to iOS 9.3 or earlier.

[image]